# Something in my code makes str_replace not work

Tags: php, html

I have a number of for-loops in my php code. In the last one you can see that i try to echo with a str_replace. When i try to replace a single letter like 'A' it works fine. But when i try with something like 'AB' it dosn't replace anything.
This is all the code.

```
$data = array();
$files = scandir('files/');
foreach($files as $file) {
    $count = 0;
    if ($filea = fopen('files/'.$file, "r")) {
        while(!feof($filea)) {
            $line = fgets($filea);
            if ($count > 1 and strlen($line)>1){
                $data[] = explode(";", $line);
            }
            $count++;
        }
        fclose($filea);
    }
}

$orgnized = array();

foreach($data as $doc){
    $bis = str_replace("AB","",$doc[1]);
    echo($bis)."</br>";
    if(!isset($orgnized[$doc[1]])){
        $orgnized[$doc[1]] = array();
    }
    $orgnized[$doc[1]][] = $doc;
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kpxs.png)

[Input File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwNJk.png)

Comment: Are you trying to replace individual A and B characters? You know that will only replace AB in combination, right? (Just making sure.)

Comment: No they are 'ab' in combination, I uploaded the output so you can get an idea of the data.

Comment: dump var $doc and check that is indeed at position 1 I suspect looking at your output that it should be position $doc[0] or possibly just $doc

Comment: There is data in $doc[0] and $doc[2] but I'm pretty sure that there's no problem there since str_replace("A") is working. Only thing i can imagine is something with characterformating, could it be something like that?

Comment: It's possible, although I'm not sure how likely. Can you edit the question to show a couple of example lines from the original files? (The actual text rather than an image would be most useful.)

Comment: Added! I don't know if it's worth mentioning but the file has been downloaded with file_put_contents("files/".$fetchdate.".txt", fopen($part, 'r')); That code is commentet out right now so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Solved. I converted the .txt file to UTF8. Weird it didn't work without that.. Thanks for you help!